# Scrolling doesn't stop, While stopping the scroll action by tapping the screen after fling action in UWP

Tags: uwp

I tried below approach while handle the ManipulationMode on Parent StackPanel (VisualContainer) and Child StackPanel (Items) as ManipulationMode.All inside placed the scroll view. But I am facing the issue that is scrolling not stopped, While stopping the scroll action by touch the screen after fling action. I am used below code.

**Issue : Scrolling is not stopped while touch the screen after perform fling action in UWP**

It is working fine for Child StackPanel (Items) ManipulationMode as System. But not working in Child StackPanel (Items) ManipulationMode as All

**Note : I must need the child stack panel (Items) ManipulationMode as ALL.**

Here I have attached the Sample Code Snippet.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App4.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App4"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>

        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer">

            <!--It is a Parent Stack Panel - VisualContainer-->

            <StackPanel Background="AntiqueWhite" x:Name="VisualContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                <!--It is a Child Stack Panel, The below views are Items-->

                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Aquamarine" Height="100" />
                <local:StackPanelExt Background="Pink" Height="100" />

            </StackPanel>

        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>

</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            VisualContainer.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;
            VisualContainer.ManipulationDelta += VisualContainer_ManipulationDelta;

        }

        private void VisualContainer_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ScrollViewer.ChangeView(0, ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset - e.Delta.Translation.Y, null, true);
        }

    }

    public class StackPanelExt : StackPanel
    {
        public StackPanelExt()
        {
            //this.ManipulationDelta += StackPanelExtExt_ManipulationDelta;
            this.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All;
        }

        private void StackPanelExtExt_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var x = e.Cumulative.Translation.X;
            var y = e.Cumulative.Translation.Y;

            if (Math.Abs(y) <= Math.Abs(x))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop the scroll by handling the ManipulationDelta event of VisualContainer once poniter is pressed after fling is started like below.

```
bool isPointerPressed = false;
    private void VisualContainer_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isPointerPressed = true;
        Debug.WriteLine("PointerPressed: " + ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset);
    }

    private void VisualContainer_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!e.IsInertial)
        {
            isPointerPressed = false;
        }
        else if(isPointerPressed)
        {
            e.Complete();
            return;
        }
        var offset = ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset - e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        ScrollViewer.ChangeView(0, offset, null, true);
    }
```

I have handled the manipulation based on isPointerPressed variable. Also determined that pointer pressed after fling by checking the IsInertial of manipulation event arguments.

Comment: Awesome answer..... Thank you so much... bro......
It is working fine...